# How to export DocC documentation as PDF?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, docc

I have created a documentation for the SDK (DocC).

I wanted to ask how to export SDK Documentation as PDF. Is there a way for that, if yes, how?

Comment: Anyone can reply?

Comment: It doesn't seem that there is an obvious way but, have you tried the HTML route and then exporting the site as a PDF? Less ideal for sure